The VBA-JSON Tool Incorrectly Converts Some Numbers to Strings?
I've been using the VBA-JSON tool for a while now and have come across an issue I've not experienced before.
My JSON data coming from an API has several long decimal values in it. The values are meant to be a number/float and when the JSON string is received from the API it's fine (there's no extra " or ' around them that implies they're a string) but when the VBA-JSON converter runs it randomly turns some of them in to type String.
The Double type should be able to hold these numbers? I can't work out what is going on.
Dim json_string As String
json_string = Sheet3.Range("A5").Value

Dim json_object As Object
Set json_object = JsonConverter.ParseJson(json_string)

I was having trouble typing the the string directly in the VBA editor so I placted it in a cell.
The exact text placed in the Cell A5 is {"Y":[-1.05,1.05,0.40700000000000003,-0.40700000000000003]}
and the value of the json_string variable shows up exactly as "{"Y":[-1.05,1.05,0.40700000000000003,-0.40700000000000003]}" in the Locals window.
After parsing, the json_object has converted the two long decimals to strings.


You have numbers which are longer than 15 digits. These are treated as text by default. Try to use option: JsonConverter.JsonOptions.UseDoubleForLargeNumbers = True according to instruction for VBA-JSON.

@MGonet unfortunately that doesn't fix it, in fact, it makes the problem worse. Now, all my long positive decimals such as (0.40700000000000003, 0.006701196205635054) turn into strings as well.

As @MGonet has pointed out already, numbers longer then 15 digits are treated as "text" in Excel application.
And, here is a Regular Expression approach to split the JSON values.
Function splitData(myRng As Range, index As Integer)
    Dim RegExp As Object
    
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegExp.Pattern = "([\d.-]+)"
    RegExp.Global = True
    
    If RegExp.Test(myRng) Then
        splitData = RegExp.Execute(myRng.Text)(index)
    Else
        splitData = ""
    End If
End Function

Assuming cell A5 is housing your JSON string, you can use the function in a cell as =splitData($A5;0) to get the first match, or; =splitData($A5;3) to get the 4th match.
My decimal separator is comma, and function argument separator character is semicolon. So, if your settings are different then this use comma instead of semicolon in the cell formulas.
Here is the screen shot showing the results and the formulas.... But remember that, numbers longer then 15 digits are treated as "text" in Excel application.
.

